# Списки, цикл for, условный оператор.

Tags: if, python-3.6, for

Интересует вопрос: как вывести элементы списка, удовлетворяющие какому-то условию, используя одну строчку кода, если это возможно?

К примеру:

Создадим список, содержащий как положительные, так и отрицательные числа. Нужно вывести на экран только положительные числа.

```
a=[]

for i in range(10):
    a.append(random.randint(-100,100))
```

Я хочу, сделать таким способом:

```
print(i for i in a if i>0)
```

Но,выводится:

```
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x00000000026AB8E0>
```

Comment: `print([i for i in a if i>0])`

Comment: @nobody,спасибо. Но, можете объяснить, почему у меня печаталось не то?

Comment: @nobody, это можно представить как:

`b=[]
for i in a:
    if i>0:
        b.append(i)
print(b)`

Правильно я понимаю?

Comment: Ну, Вы просто говорите оператору `print` вывести действие, а на самом деле, хотите получить результат. В данном случае действие это генератор объектов ссылку на который Вы и получаете, а результат Вы должны как-то типизировать, чтоб вывести его при помощи `print` на экран. Собсно, заключая генератор объектов в `[]` Вы создаёте лист объектов (лист `int` в Вашем случае), можно, например, `tuple` использовать, что Вам больше нравится. И по правилам вложенных функций интерпретатор показывает уже не ссылку на объект, а содержимое листа. Ну как-то так, рассказал как мог)